# Windows preview multiple thumbnails abnormal behaviour can't select the task

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, thumbnails

E.g. there are multiple instances of Windows Explorer. Hovering on taskbar icon  to show multiple thumbnails becomes unstable, it takes some time to move mouse to see thumbnails. However, certain instance cannot be brought to the front, click on a thumbnail clears all thumbnails without bringing focus to selected one. Clicking on taskbar icon results in thumbnails flicking and disappearing. This behaviour not from the very start, after fresh reboot all works as expected, then something in OS or certain application breaks the expected behaviour. It also affects my remote session in RDP as soon as it is broken for my home computer, similar problem does appear on remote.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try Disabling the Taskbar thumbnail view and try enabling it back after a reboot and check the behavior?.

Press Windows key+r > gpedit.msc and press enter > User Configuration in the left pane > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar > in right pane, select “Turn off Taskbar Thumbnails” > double click > Disabled. Now, go to command prompt and enter `gpupdate /force`

Reboot your machine and follow the same steps to enable the Thumbnails. Note: again go to command prompt and enter `gpupdate /force`. This will ensure the changes in the group policy will take immediate effect.